# Multiple ShellEscape compiling at the same time in .tex file

Tags: luatex, compiling, luacode

I have been working on a project, where I'm compiling a single document into differents .pdf, thanks to a trick I found. In my .tex file, I'm creating an empty .pdf to make LaTeX happy thanks to luacode, then I'm opening three Shells in a row, asking to compile the current document, with a different parameter, and outputing .pdf files with different names.

My main question is : is it be possible to run the differents `\ShellEscape` at the time, in order to gain compilation time for larger projects. At the moment, the second document starts compiling only when the first one is done, because of the linear structure.

My secondary question is : is it possible to delete the \jobname.pdf at the end of the compilation, without making LaTeX unhappy ?

My code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\RequirePackage{luacode}
\RequirePackage{shellesc}

%Creating an empty pdf to make LaTeX happy
\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \begin{luacode*}
    function create_empty_pdf()
      local pdf_file = io.open(tex.jobname .. ".pdf", "wb")
      pdf_file:write("%PDF-1.5\n%%\n%%EOF")
      pdf_file:close()
    end
    create_empty_pdf()
  \end{luacode*}
\fi

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\newcommand{\runlualatex}[2]{%#1=file name  ; #2=macro value ; ShellEscape > compiling document and defining \conditionmacro
\ShellEscape{%
  lualatex  --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --shell-escape --jobname="\jobname#1"
  "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{#2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\ShellEscape{%
  lualatex  --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --shell-escape --jobname="\jobname#1"
  "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{#2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\ShellEscape{%
  lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --shell-escape --jobname="\jobname#1"
  "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{#2}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
}%
\fi

%Creating three .pdf \jobname-fileX
\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\runlualatex{-file1}{macro1}
\runlualatex{-file2}{macro2}
\runlualatex{-file3}{macro3}
\expandafter\stop
\fi

\begin{document}

Value of the \conditionmacro

\end{document}
```

Comment: your setup seems very strange, why make the pdf (what do you mean by "happy" latex does not check if a pdf exists.  why do you have  the  `\begin` document at all? You could more simply not use shell esape and simply run a script that runs latex three times.  You can run them in parallel if your OS supports that eg end the command with `&` in bash shells

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I don't create the .pdf, my editor returns an error, even if my pdf are compiling just fine, that's why I used this workaround. I'm using a modular document, where options are defined with a seed I enter in `\conditionmacro` ; changing the output pdf appearance. I would like not to use a bash script, because I believe I should put it in the folder of my document everytime I want to make a new one.

Comment: oh that will be  bad check by your editor, nothing really related to latex.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Lua if possible (how to do that is a Lua programming question, I think e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9480315/5267751 has an answer)

But if you want to use TeX anyway it's also possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% allocate new streams
\ior_new:N \__vince_tmpa_ior
\ior_new:N \__vince_tmpb_ior
\ior_new:N \__vince_tmpc_ior

% spawn processes
\ior_shell_open:Nn \__vince_tmpa_ior {sleep~2s; touch~a1.pdf}
\ior_shell_open:Nn \__vince_tmpb_ior {sleep~2s; touch~a2.pdf}
\ior_shell_open:Nn \__vince_tmpc_ior {sleep~2s; touch~a3.pdf}

% wait for processes to finish
\ior_close:N \__vince_tmpa_ior
\ior_close:N \__vince_tmpb_ior
\ior_close:N \__vince_tmpc_ior

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

If you time the compilation, it only take 2s.